# spring cloud consul No bean named 'configServerRetryInterceptor' is defined

Tags: spring, maven, installation, spring-cloud, consul

I try to setup consul service.but i just can't start it.
my project is simple. my email : keets001@gmail.com

there are little configurations on spring.io

could someone help me? thanks a lot.

pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-consul-config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-consul-discovery -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-bus -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-bus</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-consul-dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      retry:
        initial-interval: 10
        max-interval: 20
    consul:
      consul:
        port: 8500
        host: localhost
        enabled: false
        discovery:
          preferIpAddress: true
          enabled: true
          register: true
          service-name: config-server
          hostname: localhost
bootstrap.yml:
spring:
  application:
    name: testConsulApp
```

bootstrap.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.ui.EnableConsulUi;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableConsulUi
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Bootstrap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Bootstrap.class, args);
    }
}
```

error:

```
2016-09-02 14:45:57.124  WARN 22886 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2054d744: startup date [Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 1970]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2530aeb4)
2016-09-02 14:45:57.139 ERROR 22886 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'configServerRetryInterceptor' is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:702) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1180) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.getDelegate(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:116) ~[spring-retry-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d2da9622.locate(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:1.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:89) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:1.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:633) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at consul.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:16) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:483) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_74]

[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:483)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'configServerRetryInterceptor' is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:702)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1180)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.getDelegate(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:138)
        at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d2da9622.locate(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:89)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:633)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:347)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
        at consul.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:16)
        ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.346 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-02T14:45:57+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 44M/735M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project consulClient: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: No bean named 'configServerRetryInterceptor' is defined -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: There are a few odd things about your dependencies. Nearly all of them are redundant. Does it work if you remove them all except the spring-cloud-starter-consul-all?

Comment: ok，done. It works now.

Comment: How does it work? Would you please share the experience? I met the same thing.

Comment: Replace `spring-cloud-starter-consul-all` with `spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few odd things about your dependencies. Nearly all of them are redundant. It should work if you remove them all except the spring-cloud-starter-consul-all.